# Modeling a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725966/how-to-model-my-core-data-entity) earlier, but I'm missing one important thing. I have a `NoteObject` entity and every note, without Core Data, just has an `arrayOfTag`s (which is an array of `NSStrings`). I decided to use to-many relationships to store the tags instead of an array. So I created a new "`Tags`" entity, and set up a to-many relationship from my `NoteObject` to `Tags`. This works great when every tag is related to only one note, but I'm unsure how I would go about linking one tag with multiple notes. How would I set up that relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you data modeler just make the Tags -> Notes relationship a to-many relationship. If you have already generated the Entity subclasses you will have to redo those. You will also have to be careful when creating tags to ensure uniqueness, but other than that it should be fairly straightforward. `myTag.notes` should work just as well as `myNote.tags`.

Comment: But what is myNote.tags? Is that a set? An array? I still don't understand how I'd add multiple..

Comment: It is a NSSet unless you selected the relationship as Ordered in which case it will be a NSOrderedSet.

Comment: Relationships are always NSSet or NSOrderedSet. You can get the array by calling [myNote.tags allObjects]. If you create Entity subclasses it will generate methods like [myTag addNotesObjects:myArrayOfNotes].